# Thymeleaf: how to hide the sub-menu

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I need to modify the existing sidebar of this project. I want to hide the sub-menu that I didn't select. I can't figure out how to do this.

below is the HTML file for the side bar:

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <body>
       <div th:fragment="sidebar" class="sidebar">
         <ul class="list-unstyled">
           <li th:each="postDto,iterStat : ${categories}">
             <a th:attr="aria-expanded=${#lists.contains(postDto.posturl, url)} ? 'true' : ''" 
                th:attrappend="href='#submenu'+${iterStat.index}"
                data-toggle="collapse" th:text="${postDto.categoryName}">
             </a>

             <ul th:attr="id='submenu'+${iterStat.index}" 
                th:classappend="${#lists.contains(postDto.posturl, url)} ? 'show' : ''" 
                class="list-unstyled collapse" th:each="post : ${postDto.post}">
                <li th:classappend="${#strings.contains(url, post.link)} ? 'active' : ''">
                    <a th:href="${post.link}"  th:text="${post.title}"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

`

here is the output: 
[screen shot of the sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mf2cq.png)

I selected Uploading SSS Loan Repayments under the FILE UPLOADS menu. I want to only display the sub-menu under the FILE UPLOADS but the other sub-menu under UPLOAD AND TRANSACTION STATUS , eGOVERNMENT SERVICES is also on display.

Comment: I think that you might need the help of `CSS` or `JavaScript`. Is that an option?

Comment: @Francisaskquestion will do. if it's possible thru CSS or JavaScript. Thanks

Comment: @user9483197 please note for the future that thymeleaf has nothing to do with on-client behaviour, there's javascript for that. Thymeleaf is a mere template engine.